# Seaborn barplot - column values without estimator parameter

Tags: python, dataframe, plot, bar-chart, seaborn

I am a beginner in seaborn plotting and noticed that sns.barplot shows the value of bars using a parameter called estimator.
Is there a way for the barplot to show the value of each column instead of using a statiscal approach through the estimator parameter?

For instance, I have the following dataframe:

```
data = [["2019/oct",10],["2019/oct",20],["2019/oct",30],["2019/oct",40],["2019/nov",20],["2019/dec",30]] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Period', 'Observations'])
```

I would like to plot all values ​​from the Period "2019/oct" column (10,20,30 and 40), but the bar chart returns the average of these values ​​(25) for the period "2019/oct":

```
sns.barplot(x='Period',y='Observations',data=df,ci=None)
```

How can I bring all column values ​​to the chart?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`barplot` combines values with the same `x`, unless the have a different `hue`. If you want to keep the different value for "2019/oct", you could create a new column to attribute them a different `hue`:

```
data = [["2019/oct",10],["2019/oct",20],["2019/oct",30],["2019/oct",40],["2019/nov",20],["2019/dec",30]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Period', 'Observations'])

df['subgroup'] = df.groupby('Period').cumcount()+1
sns.barplot(x='Period',y='Observations',hue='subgroup',data=df,ci=None)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution Diziet Asahi. I thought sns.barplot could have another option to solve it.